# Duda al imprimir un matriz 4x4

Tags: php

Tengo una matriz y la imprimo,pero no entiendo porque el lio de variables. no me queda claro el porque $matriz $fila, (soy mas de java y php me resulta un poco raro)

```
 $listado = array(
    array(1, 30, 50, 35),
    array(6, 18, 15, 95),
    array(8, 66, 50, 82),
    array(3, 71, 50, 41),
);

foreach ($listado as $matriz) {
    foreach ($matriz as $fila) {
        echo " $fila ";
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Los nombres los tienes un poco liados. Realmente tu listado sería la matriz. El primer bucle recorre filas, el segundo recorres cada item de la fila. No es que sea lioso, es que esos nombres distraen

Comment: Como lo harias tu?

Comment: Trivi ya te ha puesto un ejemplo. De todas formas,si estás empezando con PHP, puedes acceder al elemento con `$matriz[$x][$y]`

Answer (score 1):

Solo cambia los nombres de las variables:

- `$listado` realmente es la ***matriz*** que deseas mostrar
- `$matriz` es para recorrer cada ***fila***
- `$fila` es para recorrer cada ***elemento***

```
$matriz = array(
    array(1, 30, 50, 35),
    array(6, 18, 15, 95),
    array(8, 66, 50, 82),
    array(3, 71, 50, 41),
);

foreach($matriz as $fila) {
    foreach ($fila as $elemento) {
        echo " $elemento ";
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

> Resultado:

```
1 30 50 35  
6 18 15 95  
8 66 50 82  
3 72 50 41
```

Si deseas acceder a un elemento en específico, hay que tener en cuenta que los índices de arreglos numéricos inician en cero, el primer índice accede a la fila y el segundo al elemento, por lo que el *elemento 1* de la *fila 3* sería `$matriz[2][0]`

Cómo acceder a cada fila

```
1 30 50 35  // Fila 1  $matriz[0]
6 18 15 95  // Fila 2  $matriz[1]
8 66 50 82  // Fila 3  $matriz[2]
3 72 50 41  // Fila 4  $matriz[3]
```

Cómo acceder a cada elemento de una fila específica, en este caso, la 3

```
8 66 50 82  // Fila 3
8  // Elemento 1  $matriz[2][0]
66 // Elemento 2  $matriz[2][1]
50 // Elemento 3  $matriz[2][2]
82 // Elemento 4  $matriz[2][3]
```

Comment: Como tal, no imprimes $columnas. Imprimes elementos ... Lo suyo sería cambiar el nombre de $columna por $elemento o $celda

Comment: @Jakala, creo que `$elemento` parece más apropiado. Gracias por la observación.